# angular js filters working but with errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

**Angular js filter Working Fine But Throwing Itteration Errors**

```js
var app = angular.module('NGapp', []);
app.filter('altDate', altDate);
app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    'listProductCost': [{
      'data': 1
    }, {
      'data': 23
    }, {
      'data': 234
    }, ]
  }
}

function altDate(_) {
  return function(value) {
    console.log(value)
    if (!value || value.length === 0) {

      return [];
    } else {
      var f = []
      angular.forEach(value, function(data) {
        f.push(data['data']);
      })
      var s = []
      s.push({
        'min': _.min(f),
        'max': _.max(f)
      })
      return s;
    }

    //return s;
  };
}
app.factory('_', LodashFactory);

/** @ngInject */
function LodashFactory($window) {
  return $window._;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="NGapp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="lodash.js@4.17.4" data-semver="4.17.4" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <md-card-content layout="row" layout-align="none" ng-repeat="datas in data.listProductCost  |  altDate ">
    <div class="dark" flex="30">HO Cost</div>
    <div>
      <span>{{datas.min}}</span> % to <span>{{datas.max}}</span> %
    </div>
  </md-card-content>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my Working Code With angularjs filter . the filter is working fine but iam getting itteration error in console 
the purpose filter is to print only the minimum and maximum value of the discount. can anyone can resolve the issue or give me a idea to resolve this thanks in advance

Comment: What is it with the names `_`?

Comment: for using underscore in angularjs

Comment: Ok, but the meaning of that? To make it as less understandable as possible?

Comment: why are you returning another function from the filter?

Comment: to pass the value to the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you using lodash. Why not use _.minBy() instead of _.min() ?

That way you can reduce your *altDate* function to

```
altDate(_){
  return function(value) {
    return {
       min:  _.minBy(value, function(i) { return i.data }),
       max:  _.maxBy(value, function(i) { return i.data})
    }
  }
}
```